# How to remove dynamically added grid element in UWP

Tags: uwp

I have a page in my UWP application where the user can choose a product from the combo box.

[image]

There are 4 types of selectable products all together but 2 of them fire an event. If the user chooses "Pizza" or "Sandwich", a new Grid element is added to the display which contains toppings via the following code:

```
        Grid toppingGrid = new Grid();
        toppingGrid.Name = "toppingGrid";
        toppingGrid.Width = 1000;
        toppingGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 500, 0, 0);
        toppingGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Then there is some other code in the middle which adds the toppings into this topping grid, and finally I add the topping grid into the main grid on my page:

```
this.detailsGrid.Children.Add(toppingGrid);
```

Now when the user decides to change from Pizza to a different product, I have to remove this newly created topping grid element from display. I have an event listener on the product type combo box which fires each time the product is change, but I'm not sure how to remove the topping grid. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if (this.detailsGrid.Children.Count > 6)
            this.detailsGrid.Children.RemoveAt(7);
```

Comment: Yeah this is almost certainly not what you want to do. Check out how to use content controls, data templates and converters. Bind the converter to a selected element model and have the converter pivot on the type. It'll display the data template you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Visibility` property.

If your top grid's child is a `TextBlock`, just control it's `Visibility`.

Hope it can help you.

[image]

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. As I needed a quick solution for a DIY project this solution was sufficient rather than figuring out how to hide programmatically implemented elements.